# Inter-rater reliability for multiple raters for one item (subject)

Tags: python, reliability, agreement-statistics, cohens-kappa

I have data with 3 raters, each of whom rated 3 items as follows:

|  | item a | item b | item c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| rater 1 | a1 | b1 | c1 |
| rater 2 | a2 | b2 | c2 |
| rater 3 | a3 | b3 | c3 |

I successfully calculated the inter-rater reliability for all three items using [Krippendorff's alpha library](https://github.com/grrrr/krippendorff-alpha) as follows:

```py
krippendorff([[a1, b1, c1], [a2, b2, c2], [a3, b3, c3]])
```

Now, I am trying to calculate inter-rater reliability per item.
For example, for item a, I would like to calculate something like the following:

```
krippendorff([[a1], [a2], [a3]])
```

However, both Krippendorff's alpha and Fleiss' kappa always return 0 when the number of items equals 1. Is there an alternative metric that I can use when there is only 1 item?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Krippendorff's alpha, like the other distribution-based indexes of chance-adjusted agreement (e.g., kappa and pi), estimates chance agreement using the observed category distributions. With only a single item, you can't estimate chance agreement this way. So you are better off just using percent agreement without adjusting for chance agreement (or gathering more data).